# EPPlus not returning correct file format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, epplus

Hello I'm using EPPlus to generate Excel file but what I get is bad encoded file as shown in screenshot
[image]

Here is my code snippet:

```
 var stream = new MemoryStream();
 using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
 {
       var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Title");

       worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Hello";
       package.Save();
 }
 stream.Position = 0;
 return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "bankroll-transaction.xlsx");
```

Comment: I used your code to test, everything is running normally, no garbled characters appear. When you open the file, is there a prompt for file corruption?

Comment: @YongqingYu actually it was AutoWrapper, it was interfering with the response. I've disabled it and its working fine.

Comment: @honey_ramgarhia I am facing with exactly the same problem. What do you mean by AutoWrapper? You mean in your framework there is some module which interfere with the outgoing stream?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
return File(stream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "XXXX.xlsx")
```